# How long should it take to install Ubuntu on a netbook?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-systems, installation

I am installing Ubuntu version 10.10 for the netbook and it is taking forever. I am not sure if the installation has crashed or if it actually just takes this long. It has been about 45 minutes now. The mouse cursor is a little spinny thing (i don't know what to call it).

Comment: What speed is the drive?

What media are you installing from?

Comment: Also, there should be text above the progress bar that indicates what the installer is doing at this point in time.  What does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also depends on how much memory it has. The Live CD likes quite a lot of memory; I wouldn't try on less than 256Mb (which is what some older netbooks had).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the speed of the drive it's installing to as to how long it will take, but for slower drives that long is pretty normal (it actually took me longer then that to install to a MBP).